# Regex to select certain A tags

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm trying to create a regex pattern to extract A tags in html that have contain a specific keyword in the href attribute.

For example, if I have a block of HTML such as:

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolar site amet <a href="http://foo.com">a link</a>. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud <a href="http://bar.com">another Link</a>.
```

How can I extract the entire A tag ([a link](http://foo.com)) if it's href attribute contains the keyword "foo"?

Any advice would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have to use regex try this one:

```
<a\s+href="(?=[^"]*foo)([^"]*)">([^<]*)
```

I tried it online here: [rubular.com](http://www.rubular.com/r/SasmZtCO7D)

I am using a lookahead to find if it contains foo. Then the URL is in the first group and the "a link" is in the group 2.

Comment: `\s*` is not correct. If the space was missing it wouldn't be an `<a>` tag, it would be `<ahref>`, and invalid. Remove the `*`, or change it to `+`.

Answer (score 3):

Except for extremely trivial uses, [regular expressions are discouraged for parsing or manipulating HTML and/or XML](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/128421). The reason is that HTML and XML can vary wildly, and still be valid, causing regular expressions in your code to break in new and wonderful ways, becoming a maintenance [nightmare](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html).

This is how you should do it for anything beyond a trivial app:

```
require "nokogiri"

html = '
<p>Lorem ipsum dolar site amet <a href="http://foo.com">link 1</a>. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud <a href="http://bar.com">another Link</a>.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolar site amet <a href="http://bar.com">another link</a>. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud <a href="http://foo.com">link 2</a>.</p>
<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolar site amet <a href="http://bar.com">another link</a>.
  Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud <a href="http://foo.com">link 3</a>.
</p>
<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolar site amet <a href="http://foo.com">link 4</a>.
  Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud <a href="http://bar.com">another Link</a>.
</p>
<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolar site amet <a
    href="http://foo.com"
  >link 5</a>.
  Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud <a href="http://bar.com">another Link</a>.
</p>
'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html)

puts doc.search('//a[contains(@href, "foo")]').map{ |n| n.to_s }

>> <a href="http://foo.com">link 1</a>
>> <a href="http://foo.com">link 2</a>
>> <a href="http://foo.com">link 3</a>
>> <a href="http://foo.com">link 4</a>
>> <a href="http://foo.com">link 5</a>
```

Notice that the parser is able to find all five occurrences of the desired `<a>`, even though I deliberately mangled the last one. That mangled format is valid, and a browser will have no problem understanding it, but imagine the fun you'll have trying to generate a pattern that can capture all those variations.

Also notice that, though I pulled out a minor XPath trick to find the embedded `foo` in the href, the resulting code is much easier to read than a regex will be. I've been doing this stuff a long time, and have written a lot of regex, and, after close to 30 years that stuff still hurts my eyes.

And, lest you think that's just a trumped up example, I've run into many HTML and XML files in the wild that looked like that. It's a jungle out there, and there are some real animals generating content.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
/<\s*a[^>]+href\s*=\s*"[^"]*foo[^"]*"[^>]*>.*?<\s*\/a\s*>/
```

That should do the trick!

Comment: This one is the best so far +1. (But no need for the `\s*` after the opening `<`)

Comment: You are right ridgerunner! The [formal XML spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/) (I won't bother with SGML but I suspect it's the same there) says no whitespace characters are allowed between < and the name. You can't have whitespace between the < and / of the closing tag either, but HTML is often sloppily coded, so in the real world it's good to be generous in what you accept as valid. :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/searching_a_xml_html_document.html)?

Comment: "Have you considered using Nokogiri?" Rather than say that, actually show WHY Nokogiri is a benefit. As is, I'm tempted to downvote the answer because you didn't even try.

Comment: @the Tin Man: Yes, perhaps I should have offered this as a comment rather than an answer. I was merely trying to teach a man to fish, rather than just giving him the fish.

Comment: I think it's important to take even one more step back and help them understand why they'd want to learn to fish in the first place. The teaching part is easy once they want to learn.

Answer (score 0):

This ought to work:

```
(<a[^>]{0,}?href="([^"]{0,}foo[^"]{0,})"[^>]{0,}>[^<]+</a>)
```

Will capture the whole tag, and the href contents.